Ameliorating combinatorial explosion in proof search for linear logic
The sequent calculus for Girard's linear logic features rules that easily lead to combinatorial explosion in brute-force proof search. For example, the proof tree rule for multiplicative conjunction on the right-hand side of the turnstile is:
$\displaystyle \begin{array}{cc} \Delta_1 \vdash \Gamma_1, A & \Delta_2 \vdash \Gamma_2, B \\ \hline \Delta \vdash \Gamma, A \otimes B &  \end{array}$
where $\Delta = \Delta_1 \cup \Delta_2$ and $\Gamma = \Gamma_1 \cup \Gamma_2$. It's easy to apply this rule downwards, i.e. when I already know $\Delta_1,\Gamma_1,\Delta_2,\Gamma_2$. However, applying it upwards in a brute-force search for a proof of $\Delta \vdash \Gamma, A\otimes B$ leads to the problem that there are $2^{|\Delta|}$ possibilities for $\Delta_1$ and $2^{|\Gamma|}$ possibilities for $\Gamma_1$ to explore.
Similar remarks apply to the rule for multiplicative disjunction ⅋ to the left of the turnstile.
I've written a simple program that does automated brute-force proof search starting from the sequent one wishes to prove. However, the combinatorial explosion becomes very noticable in the run time for non-trivial examples.
Question: Is there some way to cut down the number of possibilities that need to be considered for $\Delta_1,\Gamma_1$?
For example, at least in easy cases, looking at the atoms of the formulas $A$ and $B$ and all the atoms of formulas in $\Delta$ and $\Gamma$ gives some clues to what $\Delta_1,\Gamma_1,\Delta_2,\Gamma_2$ could be. I have trouble formulating a precise rule that can be automated, though.

Have you ever heard about focusing? Also, are you interested in proof search for multiplicative linear logic only, or for exponential and/or additive as well?

@Taroccoesbrocco I'm interested mainly in MALL, i.e. additives included. Exponentials I can do without. I've read a little bit about focusing (e.g. pp. 41-43 in https://curien.galene.org/ECI2023/ll-handbook-public.pdf ), but it's not obvious to me how it helps.
